# how to add a dynamic pdfPtable into field within a existing pdf

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdf-reader, pdfptable

I have a pdf template, and I want to insert a dynamic pdfPTable within a specific field, because the table size not always be the same.

this is my code:

```
FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream(filePath);

PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4);
table.setSpacingBefore(50);
table.setSpacingAfter(50);
table.setWidthPercentage(450 / 5.23f);
table.setWidths(new int[]{1, 1, 1, 1});
table.setSplitLate(false);

table.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(0);
PdfPCell cell;
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(Veritas.INFORME_FIRMAS));
cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
cell.setColspan(4);
table.addCell(cell);
table.addCell("DNI");
table.addCell("IP Externa");
table.addCell("IP Interna");
table.addCell("Fecha de Firma");
for(int i=0; i<55;i++){
   for (Documento doc : this.documentList) {
      table.addCell(doc.getid());
      table.addCell(doc.getName());
      table.addCell(doc.getLastName());
      table.addCell(doc.getDate());
   }
}
table.setHeaderRows(3);
table.setFooterRows(1);
table.setTotalWidth(500);
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(Veritas.INFORME_BASEFILE);
// Create a stamper
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(filePath));
// Add the table to each page
PdfContentByte canvas;
for (int i = 0; i < reader.getNumberOfPages(); ) {
    canvas = stamper.getOverContent(++i);
    table.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, 50, 500, canvas);
}
// Close the stamper
stamper.close();
reader.close();
```

I show different ways to add the content. And finally I try to add the table to the end of the pdf. I can show the table but there any way to add this into the field??

And my code If the table have more rows than the page size The table isn't split. And I do the same as the itext manual said in the book "itext in ACtion".

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: An existing field has an existing, predefined size. How do you expect something with a dynamic size to fit into that?

Comment: Your interpretation of my book is wrong. You are trying to achieve something that is only possible with a dynamic XFA form, see section 8.6.2. You are using a static form.